# how to postback part of a page in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, validation, postback

I know that update panels help rendering part of a page, but what I'm asking is how to postback part of a page to server not all. I have a page that has several inside each a form that postsback some info to server. I want each submit button to postback only it's own form information not all others too.
The actual problem is that when I submit one of the forms required field of other forms won't let me do the postback. So a rephrased question might be, how do I disable validation for a button and enable it for others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use validation groups.  For example:

```
<asp:requiredfieldvalidator 
   ValidationGroup=“val_grp_1” 
   ErrorText=“Missing Value” 
   ControlToValidate=“txt_firstname” 
   runat=“server”/>
```

And then on your submit button, you reference the group you want to have validated:

```
<asp:button 
   text=“Group1” 
   ValidationGroup=“val_grp_1” 
   runat=“server”/>
```

Comment: Your validation groups dont match. `val_grp_1` and `Group1`.

Comment: Thanks, now from a performance point of view, is it possible to send only the part of information to server that I need not the whole page?

Comment: Yes -- that's the updatepanel.  Now that you're using validation groups, you should be ok.  Also, it sounds like you're using multiple forms (?), so if you put the button in the form, it would submit just that form.

Comment: No although I wanna use multiple forms, I can't I'm using an ajax toolkit with tabs on my page, each tab having a form, but I can't insert <form> tags inside tabs. I think update panel should do.

Comment: Not exactly...  You can't insert `<form>` tags inside of ** `<form>` ** tags.  But the end-result is probably as you say, if your tabs have to be inside of a form tag.